# How to align the middle section to the bottom in only portrait mode tablet without flex css

Tags: html, css

I have 3 sections, out of which in portrait mode, section 2 should come in the bottom and section 1 and 3 should align together, and in landscape mode all the 3 sections should align together.

I should support IE9 browser as well, that's the reason am not using the display flex property. Also I need to maintain the equal height, am using table cell property in my css.

This is what I tried.

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
}
.section{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.section:nth-child(1), .section:nth-child(3){
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In landscape mode do you need the sections to be in order 1-2-3, or would 1-3-2 be acceptable? That way it would be much easier to separate out section 2 (now the section 'on the end') for mobile view.

Comment: @ObsidianAge No it should be 1,2,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to set a width of 50% on both sections 1 and 3, and set a `position: absolute` on section 2, such as in the following example:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
}
.section{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.section:nth-child(1), .section:nth-child(3){
  width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .section:nth-of-type(2) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 45%;
  }
  .section:nth-of-type(1), .section:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/n6uuucbt/).

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**:

The much more simply way of going about this is if you display section three instead (or whatever section was on the right in landscape view). This way you have much more control over display, and can even work with multiple containers:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
}
.section{
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.section:nth-child(1), .section:nth-child(3){
  width: 30%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;  
  }
  .section {
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .section:nth-of-type(1), .section:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
  }
  .section:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>
```

The key here is the use of `display: block` at a narrow width, in conjunction with `float: left`. The first two sections are only 50% of the width (minus the width of the borders), so they float next to each other. The third section occupies 100% of the width of the row.

Again, due to StackOverflow being too wide to show this media query, I've created a second fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/pw0w9dd4/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is good solution, but what If I have another container outside of main container. some thing like this <div class="container">
  <div class="section">Section 1</div>
  <div class="section">Section 2</div>
  <div class="section">Section 3</div>
</div>

<div class="section-below">Section 4</div>

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide a solution where the div at the bottom won't overlap with an additional container. It requires displaying the third section at the bottom instead of the second, but is a **much** cleaner solution :)